# Bootstrap 3 vertically align text for btn-group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I vertically align a label for a custom button group with a float?

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="btn-group pull-right" role="group" aria-label="Sort By">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Friends</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Distance</button>
  </div>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <div>Sort By:</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried `vertical-align: middle` with no luck

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syy8pe7n/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `line-height`.

```
.btn-group + .pull-right div {
    line-height:2em;
}
```

Comment: @user2954587 It's not a fix-all by any means but it addresses the question as asked.  Any CSS-based approach breaks down once you start reorganizing the DOM.  Beyond that, you didn't actually use my answer in your jsfiddle, you changed the element the rule applies to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
      <span class="label label-default">Sort By:</span>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Sort By">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Friends</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Distance</button> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class to put a `position: relative` and `top: 5px` to center vertically.

HTML:

```
<div class="sort-by">Sort By:</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sort-by{
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/syy8pe7n/2/

Regards!